# How to Copy data from One Google Sheet to another Sheet in the Same file Using Sheet Name as Criteria and find the sheet base on filter criteria

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to filter data using sheet name and then copy that filters data to the sheet which I used as the filtered name. I want to filter data from the "Hirtory1" column I. The Idea is as each tab name given after the "history1" tab should be used as filter criteria. Once the data is filtered based on tab name, the data should be copied on the next blank row and automatically goto to that particular sheet one by one automatically. I am trying using the following macro but it is not working as I am looking for.

```
function CopyDAta() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A:I').activate();
  spreadsheet.setCurrentCell(spreadsheet.getRange('I1'));
  spreadsheet.getRange('A:I').createFilter();
  spreadsheet.getRange('I1').activate();
  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenTextContains(sheetName())
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(9, criteria);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('FTM'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange().copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
};
```

Here is the link to the Google sheet.
[Google sheet Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KD_qFT6J6ife72OhQRzr0pHSiyyRNA3X8KCDTc2A-iE/edit#gid=1891072242)

The step by step idea is as under.

1. [Full View of the datasheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvQ2D.png)
2. [I applied filter "FTM" on the History1 Data and copy that data to paste in the next tab title as "FTM"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDG84.png)

I above code only work for one tab. I want a way where I click and data should be sent to all tabs. The filter I applied is based on the tab name. If you see the filter criteria "FTM" is also the same as the tab name "FTM". So the code will first filter the "FTM" in the History tab and then search where the "FTM" tab is located in the entire Google Sheet and paste data there in the next empty row. Similarly, each tab will get data from history1 sheet based on its name filter criteria and populate that in the relevant sheet. My code is working but it does not search the sheet and does not paste automatically. I want to automate it, but don't know how?

Please guide me what I need to do next. Thanks

Comment: Anyone here who can tell whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Please elaborate your exact problem with more description and example

Comment: @vin I have edited my post and explain it in more detail please take a look. thanks

Comment: I am going to delete my account. anyone can tell how to do this. No body here to help out. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a completely dynamic solution - you can add or delete tickers

```
function split_history(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var hissht=ss.getSheetByName("History1");
  var hisvals=hissht.getDataRange().getValues();
  var sheets=ss.getSheets();
  for (i=0;i<sheets.length;i++){
    if (sheets[i].getName()=="Summary" || sheets[i].getName()=="History1" || sheets[i].getName()=="Main Menu" ) {} else {
      var sn=sheets[i].getName();
      var vals=[];
      for (j=1;j<hisvals.length;j++){
        if (hisvals[j][8]==sn){
          vals.push([hisvals[j][0],hisvals[j][1],hisvals[j][2],hisvals[j][3]]) ; //modify it as per your need
        }
      }
      var dsht=ss.getSheetByName(sn);
      var dlr=dsht.getLastRow();
      dsht.getRange(dlr+1,1,vals.length,4).setValues(vals); //i have used only 4 columns A,B,C,D - you can modify it

    }
  }
}
//
```

Comment: Thanks brother for your help. Highly appreciated.

Comment: It adds rows at the bottom only. If you modify the right side calculations to use arrayformula, it will be better

Comment: it is not working, nor populating results in the sheets. Can you please check where is problem in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Pl. try this code

`````
function split_history(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var hissht=ss.getSheetByName("History1");
  var hisvals=hissht.getDataRange().getValues();
  var sheets=ss.getSheets();
  for (i=0;i<sheets.length;i++){
    //
  }
  var xrp=[];
  var bnb=[];
  for (j=1;j<hisvals.length;j++){
    if (hisvals[j][8]=="XRP"){
      xrp.push([hisvals[j][0],hisvals[j][1],hisvals[j][2],hisvals[j][3]]) ; //modify it as per your need
    }
    if (hisvals[j][8]=="BNB"){
      bnb.push([hisvals[j][0],hisvals[j][1],hisvals[j][2],hisvals[j][3]])
    }

    //add all sections here

  }

  var xrpsht=ss.getSheetByName("XRP");
  var xrplr=xrpsht.getLastRow();
  xrpsht.getRange(xrplr+1,1,xrp.length,4).setValues(xrp); //i have used only 4 columns A,B,C,D - you can modify it

  var bnbsht=ss.getSheetByName("BNB");
  var bnblr=bnbsht.getLastRow();
  bnbsht.getRange(bnblr+1,1,bnb.length,4).setValue(bnb);

  //add other sections as per your need
  
}
````
`````

Comment: @ Arul Selvan Thanks bro, but is a static method. I am looking for a dynamic.